How to continue fluxMap sequence after exception
I'm new to project reactor and I've met a problem. Here is code example:
// Message has a type of SomeClass
flux.flatMap(message -> someService.someOperationReturningMono(...)
        .flatMap(i -> anotherService.operationWichCanProducerException(message.getProperty()))
                .flatMap(j -> anotherService.operationWichCanProducerException(message.getProperty())))
        .then()
                .onErrorContinue(...)
        .subscribe(...);

The problem is that first invokation can produce exception and because of this second invocation will not happend because, as I know, after first exception in chain the original Publisher finishes, but for me it's important to gurantee second invokation of the service method. Moreover, in future, there are gonna be more of those invokations, because the actual parameters are always different. Is there any way to gurantee that if any exception occurs during service method invokation - service methods from next flatMaps will still be invoked?
EDIT 1:
I want to add some context to my problem: method from serviceA suppose to send kafka messages (asynchroniously, so the return type of their methods is Mono<Void>) with different type (WEB message, EMAIL message, etc) on specific topic (the same for every message). Here is temproary workaround that seems to work with seriveA method just printing string in concole (did't check it with kafka yet)
Mono<FakeDbRecord> mono = Mono.just(new FakeDbRecord("Propety"));

        mono.flatMap(message -> serviceC.someRandomLogic()
                .flatMap(i -> serviceA.methodA(message.getSomeProperty(), Types.WEB).then(Mono.just(message)))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    System.out.println("BOOOOOOOOOOM!!!!! " + e.getMessage());

                    return Mono.just(message);
                })
                .flatMap(j -> serviceA.methodA(message.getSomeProperty(), Types.EMAIL).then(Mono.just(message)))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    System.out.println("BOOOOOOOOOOM!!!!! " + e.getMessage());

                    return Mono.just(message);
                })).subscribe();

In actual code I'm getting a record from db (message), then this record is being proccesed with some random logic (serviceC.someRandomLogic()) and if everything is fine - we are sending notifications to kafka
Is it actually a good solution for my problem? Or maybe there are better ways?

Do not let the operationWichCanProducerException throw an exception ?

No, this operation can throw an exeption or can not, no matter if it throws it or not, I want to make sure all other invokations of operationWichCanProducerException will happend

I don't think you understood my suggestion, it was to do exactly what you asked for. Either change the method to be surrounded by a try/catch and return null in case of error, or do so directly on the flatmap operation .flatMap( j -> { try{ return methodCallHere(...); }catch(Exception e){ return null; } })

You are a life saver, that's working, thank you for solution. But instead of null I'm returnin Mono.just(message) and it's also possible to return Mono.empty() (but in this case need to change next 'flatMap' operarator to 'then' and include Monod.defer()).

Hm, I ve just tested - if first service method call will not provoke an exception and returns Mono (that's what it returns by contract) - then I'm loosing message from the context for future methods invokations. Still instead of returning method result I can just return Mono.just(message), but is it a good practice? I understand, that my service method return Mono so no difference I think, but still?

It all depends on your requirements. I can't tell you though that the chained operation is the wrong approach if you need all operations to run regardless. You need to review your requirements, specially why do you absolute need the second one to run if the first failed, are you talking about two different calls to the chain or the second call within the chain, I couldn't understand the difference...

Sorry, this "I can't tell you though that" read "I CAN TELL"

So if the chained operation is wrong approach, which will be the better one? So the context of this thing is: there is a message comes from kafka and we need need to update status of it in db (everything is done in reactive style), after this there are two notifications should be sent with different types. On codereview my collegue said, that if first notification wasn't sent, still it should not affect the second one, so the second one be sent.

Given your that in your code each operation depends on the prior and it is using flux, you could use the Saga pattern (I apologize i did not consider the reactive part of it first). Essentially doing what you said returning a Mono would work, though you could change it a bit to be more elegant with the pattern I suggested. The difference is that your code would be more elegant and with a better communication between the steps (flatmap operations). And instead of just returning a Mono define a message that the other steps can understand what happened in the chain.

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

Another pattern you can use if you want to have a more specialized control of your steps would be the Reactive Orchestration Pattern

Sorry, I did not notice your first message before link to patterns. No, operations are not depending on each other, please, checkout my EDIT1 in this question, I think I explained it better there

You say the operations does not depend on each other however your code is structured such it is depending on the result of the first call (the message parameter from the first flatMap on subsequent calls). So you need to ask yourself, does these operations needs to work sequentially or in parallel? Depending the answer you can use different patterns, if sequentially you can use Saga if not you can use Pipeline.
